# read() stops after NUL character

Tags: python, nul

I'm downloading files over HTTPS, I request the files through `urllib2.Request` and they come back as a `socket._fileobject`. I'd ideally like to stream this to file to avoid loading it into memory but I'm not sure how to do this.

My problem is if I call `.read()` on the object it only returns all the data up to the first NUL character and doesn't read the whole file. How can I solve this?

The NUL character comes down as `\x00` if that's any help, not sure what encoding that is

Comment: May be you should validate if data after  \X00 is allowed in protocal. Have you try some other library, like curl in python http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: The `.read()` method in general doesn't care about NUL bytes.  Can you show us your code and some sample input that triggers the problem?

Comment: Well not easily because the file comes from a server which requires authentication. Weirdly `.readlines()` gets the whole file as a list separated by the `\n` characters as expected but `read()` just returns `MZ` as the file starts `MZ       ÿÿ` where the white space is NUL bytes. Why doesn't `read` work where `readlines` does? Should I just use `"".join` on the `readlines` to get the file contents?

Comment: Calling `.read()` does not read the entire data.  You have to keep calling it to get all of the data.  Please share some code.

Comment: Any suggestions what code I should share? I can't give the call that returns the fileobject because it wont work because of the authentication. I thought `.read()` did read the entire data, if I call it again multiple times it returns nothing. (Interestingly `"".join(f.readlines())` returns just `MZ` like `.read()` does.)

Comment: Think this is something to do with the strings getting turned into C strings which are NUL terminated. How can I get around this?

Comment: We can't assist you in this case without seeing exactly what your client code is doing.

Comment: Argh... I just worked out what the problem is.. I was running the code  inside PyScripter and the in-built python interpreter terminates NUL bytes in strings it seems. So there was no problem with my code, if I run it outside PyScripter everything works fine.

Comment: @GP89, you should post this as an answer, and accept it, so if any other folks stumble upon the same issue, they can find the answer without having to dig through the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was that I was running the code inside PyScripter and the in-built python interpreter terminates NUL bytes in the output. So there was no problem with my code, if I run it outside PyScripter everything works fine. Now running Wing IDE and never looking back :)