# Conitnue to read through NUL

Tags: python, string, file, nul

I got a .dat file, encoded in ANSI which contains NUL caracters (not only !).

I wan't to read it into a str object iot cut something in the whole str obtained.

But `file.read()` stops when the first NUL is reached.

I'm lost :)

My code :

```
file=open(source, mode='rt')
fulltext=file.read()
print(fulltext)
```

NUL is show with Notepad++ I'm on Windows XP, with PortablePython 3.2
The file is a special DAT file that can be edited with notepad as a text.

Comment: I don't think EOF and NUL (you mean just 0?) are the same, so `file.read()` shouldn't stop. Can you show us the code you use, and tell us 1) the Python version you're using, and 2) what platform you're on?

Comment: It may be that pyscripter is the problem. The "Related" sidebar showed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581963/read-stops-after-nul-character?rq=1) , which has a similar problem (socket conn. instead of a file), where the resolution was not to use pyscripter.

Comment: THX Evert ! I can't pay for an IDE like Wing IDE. I tried my code into a batch DOS file ... with the python.exe instead of the pythonw.exe.

Comment: and it works WELL ! THX Evert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Evert has commented in my question, the problem was focused on the use of Pyscripter !
So, this question is closed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read bytes like `0`, chances are your file is a binary file. Read in binary mode `rb` instead of text mode `rt`.

Comment: `\x00` is how you encode NUL byte in Python string literals. The file is probably read properly so look how you're printing it.

Comment: But 13MB of data won't fit on a screen anyway