# Reading till end of file in python

Tags: python, file, file-io

I am reading a .exe file in binary format in python. In this, the hex editor shows null after 3 bytes. After few bytes, there is data present. But, when I am using read() function it stops until the first null occurs. Being a beginner in python, I searched up but couldn't find a solution. Here is a screenshot of file in hex editor.
http://prntscr.com/e7ubkd 
**Thank you**

Comment: `read()` reads until `EOF`, not `\x00`.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490794/conitnue-to-read-through-nul

Comment: @NPE but the read() is reading till \x00 but EOF. That's what troubling me.